# How can I insert a document containing integer field in Mongodb with document validation using pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to insert a document in MongoDB having document validation using pymongo. It has a type validator to check for data types.

```
db.createCollection( "final",
 { validator: { $and:
     [
         { name: { $type: "string" } },
         { number: { **$type: "int"**} }
     ]
 }
} )
```

When I insert a document using mongo shell i can insert data in integer field by using **NumberInt()**.

```
db.final.insert({ name: "abc", number: **NumberInt(4465)**})
```

How can I insert a document with integer field using pymongo?